Sending AT commands to GSM via STM32, TX buffer error
I'm developing a system with a GMS module, where AT commands are sent to the module via an STM32.
In this case, I'm having problems with the AT+CSTT command, which was giving me an ERROR. After a lot of thought, I realized that the error was due to the fact that the command was going to the module with the T for AT missing (A+CSTT).
I'm working with the commands like this:
void sendAT(char command[], char answer[], int waitForAnswer) {
    char ATcommand[500];
    uint8_t buffer[500] = { 0 };
    uint8_t ATisOK = 0;

    sprintf(ATcommand, "%s\r\n", command);

    DEBUG_PRINT("Sending AT Command: ");
    DEBUG_PRINT(ATcommand);

    while (!ATisOK) {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) ATcommand, strlen(ATcommand),
                2000);
        
        
        HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 300);
        buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1] = '\0';

        HAL_Delay(500);

        ATisOK = !waitForAnswer;

        if (strstr((char*) buffer, "OK")) {
            ATisOK = 1;
        }

        DEBUG_PRINT("GSM: ");
        DEBUG_PRINT((char* ) buffer);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }
}

char* sendATWithReturn(char command[]) {
    char ATcommand[500];
    uint8_t buffer[300] = { 0 };
    char *returnBuffer = malloc(300 * sizeof(char));

    if (returnBuffer == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    sprintf(ATcommand, "%s\r\n", command);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) ATcommand, strlen(ATcommand), 1000);
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, buffer, 300, 100);
    HAL_Delay(500);

    DEBUG_PRINT("GSM: ");
    DEBUG_PRINT((char* ) buffer);

    strncpy(returnBuffer, (char*) buffer, 300);

    return returnBuffer;
}

And my command sequence goes like this:
void modemStart(char *apn, char *user, char *pwd) {
    sendATWithReturn("AT");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CPIN?");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CREG?");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CGATT?");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CSQ");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    char command[500];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"%s\"", apn);
    sendAT(command, "OK", 1);
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendAT("AT+CGATT=1", "OK", 0);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CSTT?");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "AT+CSTT=\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"", apn, user, pwd);
    sendAT(command, "OK", 1);
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CIICR");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CIFSR");

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    sendATWithReturn("AT+CIPMUX=1");

    /*
     AT+CPIN?: Verifica o status do PIN do SIM.
     AT+CREG?: Verifica o status de registro na rede.

     Sequência de Inicialização:

     AT+NETCLOSE: Fecha qualquer conexão de rede existente.
     AT+CGATT=0: Desativa o GPRS.
     AT+CGATT=1: Ativa o GPRS.
     AT+CGDCONT: Define o contexto PDP.
     AT+CSTT: Define o APN, usuário e senha.
     AT+CIICR: Inicia a conexão sem fio.
     AT+CIFSR: Obtém o endereço IP.
     AT+CIPMUX=1: Habilita o modo de múltiplas conexões.
    */
}

LOG:
19:37:54.671 -> Serial2: Send AT:
19:37:54.671 -> Sending AT Command: AT
19:37:54.671 -> GSM: AT

19:37:54.671 -> OK
19:37:54.671 -> 
19:37:56.282 -> Serial2: GSM: AT

19:37:56.282 -> OK
19:37:56.282 -> 
19:37:57.878 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CPIN?

19:37:57.878 -> +CPIN: READY
19:37:57.878 -> 
19:37:57.878 -> OK
19:37:57.878 -> 
19:37:59.455 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CREG?

19:37:59.455 -> +CREG: 0,1
19:37:59.455 -> 
19:37:59.455 -> OK
19:37:59.455 -> 
19:38:01.060 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CGATT?

19:38:01.060 -> +CGATT: 1
19:38:01.060 -> 
19:38:01.060 -> OK
19:38:01.060 -> 
19:38:04.242 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CSQ

19:38:04.242 -> +CSQ: 18,0
19:38:04.242 -> 
19:38:04.242 -> OK
19:38:04.242 -> Sending AT Command: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","zap.vivo.com.br"
19:38:04.287 -> GSM: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","zap.vivo.com.br"

19:38:04.287 -> OK
19:38:04.287 -> 
19:38:06.839 -> Serial2: Sending AT Command: AT+CGATT=1
19:38:06.839 -> GSM: AT+CGATT=1

19:38:06.885 -> OK
19:38:06.885 -> 
19:38:11.069 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CSTT?

19:38:11.069 -> ERROR
19:38:11.069 -> Sending AT Command: AT+CSTT="zap.vivo.com.br","vivo","vivo"
19:38:11.069 -> GSM: A+CSTT="zap.vivo.com.br","vivo","vivo"

19:38:11.069 -> ERROR
19:38:11.069 -> 
19:38:12.670 -> Serial2: GSM: A+CSTT="zap.vivo.com.br","vivo","vivo"

19:38:12.670 -> ERROR

In other words, the error is when the command is sent to the module, more precisely in the byte buffer conversion line, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Apparently with two characters in the password the command is sent correctly, but with more than two the AT loses its T, I tested it this way:
19:28:09.621 -> Serial2: GSM: AT+CSTT=“zap.vivo.com.br”,“vivo”,"dd”
19:28:09.621 -> ERROR

Note that AT+CSTT is correct.
Doing some more tests, I realized that the error is in the part of sending and receiving the data by Serial, since even the DEBUG_PRINT that occurs before the while click to send the command is correct.

Dropped characters on serial are usually a sign of incorrect flow control.

You are allocating memory in sendATWithReturn(). Where are you going to free it? -- To check for flow control issues, insert a delay for each single character. -- Are you sure the GSM module understands AT+CSTT? Did you try it with a common terminal program?

Well... Apparently the CSTT command doesn't really exist, I ended up basing it on an old library and not paying attention to the manual.
But thank you all, I got a good result by implementing the buffer and the interrupts.
Here's the code for anyone who wants to deal with a stack of AT commands and GSM modems:
typedef enum {
    FREE = 0,
    WAITING = 1,
    RX = 2,
    PROCESSING = 3
} GSMStatus;


uint8_t Rx_buffer[100];
uint8_t Rx_data = 0;
int rx_index = 0;

uint16_t lastRxTick = 0;

GSMStatus gsmStatus = FREE;

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (huart->Instance == huart1.Instance) {

    }
    if (huart->Instance == huart2.Instance) {
         GSM_RX_Callback();
    }
}

uint16_t sendTick = 0;
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (huart->Instance == huart1.Instance) {

    }
    if (huart->Instance == huart2.Instance) {
         GSM_TX_Callback();
    }
}

void GSM_RX_Callback(){
    //if (gsmStatus != PROCESSING) {
        Rx_buffer[rx_index++] = Rx_data;
        lastRxTick = HAL_GetTick();
        gsmStatus = RX;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &Rx_data, 1);
    //}
}

void GSM_TX_Callback(){
    if (gsmStatus == FREE) {
        gsmStatus = WAITING;
        sendTick = HAL_GetTick();
    }
}

void resetBuffers(){
    Rx_data = 0;
    rx_index = 0;
    memset(Rx_buffer, 0, sizeof(Rx_buffer));
}

char* sendAT(char command[], char answer[], int waitForAnswer) {
    char ATcommand[200];
    uint8_t commandBuffer[200] = { 0 };
    uint8_t ATisOK = 0;

    uint8_t rx_answer[100];

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &Rx_data, 1);

    snprintf(ATcommand, sizeof(ATcommand), "AT%s\r\n", command);

    memcpy(commandBuffer, (uint8_t*) ATcommand, strlen(ATcommand) + 1);

    DEBUG_PRINT("Sending AT Command: \r\n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(ATcommand);

    HAL_Delay(100);

    int retries = 0;

    while (!ATisOK) {
        if (gsmStatus == FREE) {
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, commandBuffer, sizeof(commandBuffer));
        }

        if (gsmStatus == PROCESSING) {
            rx_answer[sizeof(rx_answer) - 1] = '\0';

            ATisOK = !waitForAnswer;

            if (strstr((char*) rx_answer, "OK")) {

                DEBUG_PRINT("GSM answer: \r\n");
                char ATanswer[200];
                sprintf(ATanswer, "%s\r\n", (char*) rx_answer);
                DEBUG_PRINT(ATanswer);

                resetBuffers();
                ATisOK = 1;
                break;
            }

            if (strstr((char*) rx_answer, "ERROR")) {
                if (waitForAnswer == 1) {

                    if(retries >= 10){
                        //DEBUG_PRINT("Erro ao enviar o comando AT: \r\n");
                        resetBuffers();
                        ATisOK = 1;
                        break;
                    }

                    gsmStatus = FREE;
                    retries++;
                    HAL_Delay(200);
                } else {
                    resetBuffers();
                    ATisOK = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            memset(rx_answer, 0, sizeof(rx_answer));
            HAL_Delay(100);
            gsmStatus = FREE;
        }

        if (gsmStatus >= WAITING) {

            if (gsmStatus == RX) {
                if (HAL_GetTick() >= lastRxTick + 100) {
                    memcpy(rx_answer, Rx_buffer, sizeof(Rx_buffer));

                    rx_index = 0;
                    memset(Rx_buffer, 0, sizeof(Rx_buffer));
                    gsmStatus = PROCESSING;
                }
            }
            if (gsmStatus != PROCESSING) {
                if (HAL_GetTick() >= sendTick + 120000) {
                    DEBUG_PRINT("TimeOut\r\n");
                    resetBuffers();
                    gsmStatus = FREE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    resetBuffers();

    char *returnBuffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(returnBuffer, (char*) rx_answer, 100);

    return returnBuffer;
}

void modemStart(char *apn, char *user, char *pwd) {
    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("+CPIN?", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("+CREG?", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("+CSQ", "OK", 1));

    char command[200];

    HAL_Delay(500);
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "+CGAUTH=1,1,\"%s\",\"%s\"", user, pwd);
    free(sendAT(command, "OK", 1));
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"%s\"", apn);
    free(sendAT(command, "OK", 1));
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("+CGACT=1,1", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    free(sendAT("+CGATT?", "OK", 1));
}

void sendHTTPGet() {
    free(sendAT("+HTTPINIT", "OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\""","OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPACTION=0", "OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPREAD", "OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPTERM", "OK", 1));
}

